# Wordpress widget - backend button online/offline

Tags: wordpress, widget, backend

Hi all developers — hope there is a clever brain in here who can help.

I have a simple feature I want to implement to a site without much WP backend experience.

It is a "live chat on / off" widget/button which must be visible to operators in the dashboard. It’s purpose is to change a line in header.php / or change stylesheet for changing a picture in the frontend of the website from “offline" to "online”. I don’t have any experience in backend WP, but mostly doing website templates changes with css.

I’ve made a very simple “widget” in the backend - it’s just a wysiwyg editor button.
http://pasteboard.co/2aNHvpCa.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Therefore you could [implement a plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), which brings along a [widget](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) for showing offline or online status on the website's frontend.

As plugins can have a [settings page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages), where options for that offline/online functionality could be saved, it shouldn't be a problem to access the option field in the widget.

Have a look at [Wp-Live-Chat-Support](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-live-chat-support/screenshots/) and it's screenshots, especially the one with caption `Settings page of WP Live Chat Support`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already got iflychat.com going as a chat, but it's my "own" online/offline batch I want to be able to change from the backend.

And yes, I wan't to make a simple plugin, or "call" from the one widget i've already made, but I got no experience in that, at all... That's the problem :-)

Comment: Then go try building a simple plugin. Beneath the links i provided, there should be hundreds of tutorials of how to build a plugin in the internet. Good Luck

Comment: It's not my goal to be able to code a plugin, I would need to learn simple coding first :-) 
But I guess I need someone who can build the plugin for me.